# How to Change Eclipse Window Icon

Tags: eclipse, window, icons, branding

I would like to change the icon of my eclipse installation permanently. So when I run eclipse it should have the changed icon in **task bar** in **alt+tab** list (actually everywhere but those 2 are the ones I care about). No, I only have one workspace I work with. I just need another icon. Is it possible without installing another plug-in ?

**Edit:**
This question is about programming because my programming lacks of efficiency because I have to circle at least once around the whole tab circle to stop at the right icon. I even changed the Alt+Tab display to look like XP because it is quick for the eye to recognize the correct icon (-> more efficient task switching). I liked the old purple circle so I can find it in a blink of an eye. Not it's more gray and blends to much with the background.

Like this (green "circle" is Eclipse):

[image]

I use:
**Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 1

Build id: 20120920-0800

Windows 7**

Does eclipse run from a jar file ? Which one is responsible for the main window ? Maybe it contains the icon ?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for Super User, flagging to migrate.

Comment: @Gnoupi It is more programming related than configuration related, so I do not think it belongs at Super User

Comment: @Veger - you want to change the icon of an exe file for Windows. It's directly under the scope of SuperUser. It's acceptable on SO because it concerns a programming tool, but that's all.

Comment: @Gnoupi Except you need to create a small plugin (I know, the OP does not want it) to do so properly. Which is domain of SO instead of SU. (Also I am wondering whether your method works, as Eclipse is Java based and the exe-file is only a simple 'launcher' to find Java and launch the correct java application/class)

Comment: I created a gist which explains how to do that: https://gist.github.com/bandola/d3d7fd75ee689c2b989b#file-changing-eclipse-icon-md

Comment: @MarlonBernardes Thanks, but it worked after changing the gifs. I changed my Alt + Tab window to look like good old XP style in the image above.

Comment: Updated the link https://gist.github.com/marlonbernardes/d3d7fd75ee689c2b989b

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has an API for branding, which can be used to change the Eclipse branding to a custom branding. This includes changing the icon, the name of the application, splash screen, and so on.

[This Eclipse article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html) describes how to brand an Eclipse 3.x application. Eclipse 4.x allows you to create a custom application, it is different than for Eclipse 3.x, but it also involves providing some details to a XMl file, for more information and a tutorial, see the [Eclipse Products and Deployment tutorial of Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html).

Unfortunately not without creating a (very) small plugin. But you do need to store the new icons somewhere, so creating such a storage plugin including a small XML file with some extension points should not be too difficult.

Comment: I created a gist which explains how to do that: https://gist.github.com/marlonbernardes/d3d7fd75ee689c2b989b

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this [How-to](http://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/), which is common to all exe files.

It involves using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), to change the icon file used in the exe file:

[image]

You could use it on eclipse.exe, and it should give you the result you expect.

Comment: *I'm giving only small details, as I'd rather not copy-paste HTG's content.*

Comment: That doesn't work. It changes the icon of the exe only.

Comment: Why did you pick this as correct answer if this does not work?